# Allowing relative pathing for front-end with ExpressJS back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

I'm busy building an application using Express 4.14. With regards to routing, when the request comes in as "https://example.com/page" for example I'm using `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/../client/pages/page/index.html");`.

The front-end dev is using relative links in the pages to include his ReactJS scripts - for instance he'd use a tag like `<script src="js/index.js"></script>`. The problem is, of course, that the request for `js/index.js` is going to the NodeJS server and returning a 404 because there is no file `/js/index.js` from the root of the project  but rather in `client/pages/home/js/index.js`. Is there some way to allow relative pathing from the page folder?

I was playing around with `express.static` middleware but the issue is that there are multiple pages, each with their old folder - they're separated into their own little SPA so to make a single `/public` static directory isn't really viable with the current setup.

This is the file directory setup:

```
project
|- server.js
|   |- node_modules
|   |- config
|   |- controllers
|   |- models
|   |- client
|      |- pages (Splitting the pages into React SPA)
|         |- pageFolder (React SPA, one per module we need.)
|            |- page.html
|            |- other files here..
```

The controller that routes to the client-side is `controllers/clientCtrl.js` which serves `index.html` in `client/pages/pageFolder`.

In `index.html` when trying to include say `index.js` in `pageFolder` the response is `Cannot GET /index.html` because it is sending the request to the NodeJS server rather than looking in the current directory.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you guys using react-router? If you are building a SPA the routing should be handled on the front end and express should just serve  `index.html` and not handle any other routes other than your API... your question doesnt make any sense to me

Comment: I am not handling the front-end, only the back-end. I am only serving `index.html` like you said. But in the `index.html`, he is struggling to include javascript files. I will edit the question to try explain better.

Comment: You guys should incorporate webpack with your build so that all relevant scripts get combined into a single bundle https://webpack.github.io/ it will make your lives much easier

Comment: I will suggest it! Do I then only serve the one js file?

Comment: Also, do you have a solution for the current situation?

Comment: Exactly - with the most basic config you would just be serving a single js file... from index.html for your entire web app.  Also your front end developer should look at the documentation for react router https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/docs

Comment: There is the issue though, I think he might be incorporating webpack already. But it's how to include the `index.js` in the `index.html`. He cannot use the typical html tags because it is returning a 404 from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, there are good reasons to use let react or express handle all of the routing. If that's not allowed for your current assignment, you probably do want to use express.static with a full directory.

By having an index.html and a webpacked bundle, you can split other pages up into subdirectories, and make sure that the relative pathing points to the static html and js files.

For example, if index.html lived in

`public
 - index.html
 - bundle.js
 - pagefolder
 - - page.html
 - - page.js`

as long as you serve the entire public directory, links from index.html to `./pagefolder/page.html`  will be valid and so on.